# How do I get a list of the visible nodes in a Flex Tree?

Tags: apache-flex, tree, flex3

I have a basic Tree built in Flex.  The Tree works fine.  I'm attempting to get a list of all of the visible nodes.  I know there is a Tree.openItems, but that does not suffice because (for example) if you open all the items in your tree and then close the root, the invisible opened items are still counted.

I simply want a list of all the visible items.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, did you get this figured out? If so, maybe you could post the the iteration loop that you used, would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop though the data items and call `Tree.isItemVisible(item)` for each.